# Using Dapper Dot Net get last inserted id

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using **Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web** to develop the MVC5 application. I want to get last inserted ID by using Dapper dot net. I got solutions here but they are working on SQL Server 2012 (Management Studio) but when I run the query in code then returning value is wrong. Here are pieces of code that I have tried already to get last inserted ID

```
SqlConnection _db = new SqlConnection("String");

        string query_1 = @"DECLARE @InsertedRows AS TABLE (user_id int);Insert into users (stuff) OUTPUT Inserted.user_id INTO @InsertedRows values(@stuff); SELECT user_id FROM @InsertedRows";
        string query_2 = @"Insert into users (stuff) OUTPUT Inserted.user_id values(@stuff);";
        string query_3 = @"Insert into users (stuff) values(@stuff); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

        1. var id = _db.Query<int>(query_x, new { stuff = @stuff });
        2. var id = _db.Execute(query_x, new { stuff = @stuff });
```

but the value of ID in both cases is 1 but not actual result. but when I run the same query on SQL management Studio then all things okay. Please help to fix this problem.

Comment: `OUTPUT Inserted` **FYI, this may be slower than using SCOPE_IDENTITY and was fixed in update #5 to SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I am going to answer my own asked question  I got answer after some other search in Dapper we have a Extension Method `.Single()`  that will return the value of Selectd value newly added i.e.

```
var id = _db.Query<int>(query_x, new { stuff = @stuff }).Single();
```

in my case it will return the value of newly added primary key value. I just add the `.Single()` function to get newly added value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using SCOPE_IDENTITY()
(Docu at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx:
Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column **in the same scope**. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch)

You probably want the result from IDENT_CURRENT()
(Docu at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx:
Returns the last identity value generated for a specified table or view. The last identity value generated can be for **any session and any scope**.)